# Checking that a value contains only digits, regex or no?

Tags: php, regex, validation

I have a function that is used throughout my code. The function expects that the passed parameter is a positive integer. Since PHP is loosely typed, the data type is unimportant. But it *is* important that it contain nothing but digits. Currently, I am using a regular expression to check the value before continuing.

**Here is a *simplified* version of my code:**

```
function do_something($company_id) {
    if (preg_match('/\D/', $company_id)) exit('Invalid parameter');
    //do several things that expect $company_id to be an integer
}
```

I come from a Perl background and tend to reach for regular expressions often. However, I know their usage is controversial.

I considered using `intval()` or `(int)` and **forcing** `$company_id` to be an integer. However, I could end up with some unexpected values and I want it to *fail fast*.

**The other option is:**

```
if (!ctype_digit((string) $company_id)) exit('Invalid parameter');
```

Is this scenario a valid use of regular expressions? Is one way preferred over the other? If so, why? Are there any gotchas I haven't considered?

Comment: What's wrong with `ctype_digit`?

Comment: The only drawback I see with `ctype_digit` is that it must be cast to a string first. However, I find the `regex` easier to read and it's what I am used to. I was trying to determine if there was a compelling reason to switch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The Goal

The original question is about validating a value of unknown data type and discarding all values except those that contain **nothing but digits**. There seems to be only two ways to achieve this desired result.

If the goal is to *fail fast*, one would want to check for invalid values and then fail rather than checking for valid values and having to wrap all code in an `if` block.

### Option 1 from Question

```
if (preg_match('/\D/', $company_id)) exit('Invalid parameter');
```

Using `regex` to fail if match non-digits. Con: regex engine has overhead

### Option 2 from Question

```
if (!ctype_digit((string) $company_id)) exit('Invalid parameter');
```

Using `ctype_digit` to fail if FALSE. Con: value must be cast to string which is a (small) extra step

You must cast value to a string because `ctype_digit` expects a string and PHP will not cast the parameter to a string for you. If you pass an integer to `ctype_digit`, you will get unexpected results.

This is documented behaviour. For example:

```
ctype_digit('42'); // true
ctype_digit(42); // false (ASCII 42 is the * character)
```

### Difference Between Option 1 and 2

Due to the overhead of the regex engine, option two is probably the best option. However, worrying about the difference between these two options may fall into the premature optimization category.

**Note:** There is also a functional difference between the two options above. The first option considers `NULL` and empty strings as valid values, the second option does not (as of PHP 5.1.0). That may make one method more desirable than the other. To make the `regex` option function the same as the `ctype_digit` version, use this instead.

```
if (!preg_match('/^\d+$/', $company_id)) exit('Invalid parameter');
```

**Note:** The 'start of string' `^` and 'end of string' `$` anchors in the above `regex` are very important. Otherwise, `abc123def` would be considered valid.

### Other Options

There are other methods that have been suggested here and in other questions that **will not achieve the stated goals**, but I think it is important to mention them and explain why they won't work as it might help someone else.

- `is_numeric` allows exponential parts, floats, and hex values
- `is_int` checks data type rather than value which is not useful for validation if `'1'` is to be considered valid. And form input is always a string. If you aren't sure where the value is coming from, you can't be sure of the data type.
- `filter_var` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` allows negative integers and values such as `1.0`. This seems like the best function to actually validate an integer regardless of data type. But doesn't work if you want *only* digits. **Note:** It's important to check `FALSE` **identity** rather than just truthy/falsey if `0` is to be considered a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

What about `filter_var` + `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` ?

```
if (FALSE === ($id = filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))) {
    // $_GET['id'] does not look like a valid int
} else {
    // $id is a int because $_GET['id'] looks like a valid int
}
```

Besides, it has min_range/max_range options.

The base idea of this function is more or less equivalent to :

```
function validate_int($string) {
    if (!ctype_digit($string)) {
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return intval($string);
    }
}
```

Also, if you expect an integer, you could use `is_int`. Unfortunately, type hinting is limited to objets and array.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods will cast the variable into a string. `preg_match` does not accept a subject of type integer so it will be cast to a string once passed to the function. `ctype_digit` is definitely the best solution in this case.

Comment: `Both methods will cast the variable into a string.` That's true... except with `preg_match`, PHP does that for you. Whereas with `ctype_digit`, you need to do it yourself.