# Check if user enters numbers ONLY, PHP

Tags: php, validation

I have this inupt field

```
 <p style="font-size: 18px;">Total Bids: <input type="text" class="total_bids" name="total_bids" placeholder="No. of Bids"></p>
```

getting its value via:

```
var totalbids = document.getElementsByName('total_bids')[0].value;
```

and getting the value in PHP via

```
$total_bids = PSF::requestGetPOST('totalbids');
```

Everything working fine, but it is supposed to take number value ONLY, so I am trying to check if user only enters a number, how can I define alphabet range so that I can set the check something like

```
if( $total_bids== 'alphabet range')
        {
           return json_encode(array('error' => 'Please enter a valid Number.'));
        }
```

Comment: `if (is_numeric($numberOrLetters)) { ... }`??? [php.net docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)

Comment: here is you answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779209/checking-that-a-value-contains-only-digits-regex-or-no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you could disallow the person to enter anything but numbers in the `<input../>` by defining it's type as `type="number"`.

Obviously, people could go around it so you still need to check it in the backend for that, you'll need to use a function like [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php).

Answer (score 2):

You can use RegEx and the `\d` Expression. `\d` matches only numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can check by [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/is_numeric)

```
if(!is_numeric($total_bids))
{
    return json_encode(array('error' => 'Please enter a valid Number.'));
}
```

Also if you want do any special checks, you can use regexp by [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match), for example:

```
if(!preg_match('~^[\d\.]$~', $total_bids))
{
    return json_encode(array('error' => 'Please enter a valid Number.'));
}
```

Regexp more flexible, you can add your own rules to check by regexpm but is_numeric check faster then regexp check

Answer (score 1):

as per your input if you need only numbers then try `ctype_digit`:

```
$strings = array('1820.20', '10002', 'wsl!12');//input with quotes is preferable.
foreach ($strings as $testcase) {
    if (ctype_digit($testcase)) {
        echo "The string $testcase consists of all digits.\n";
    } else {
        echo "The string $testcase does not consist of all digits.\n";
    }
}
```

see here :http://php.net/ctype_digit

Comment: This is bad example, because ctype_digit(43) will return false, it will work as well only for strings

Comment: @AntonOhorodnyk it should be string quoted.see the example and is the best to check numbers.and for your information the op's input is of type text.

Comment: better use is_numeric for this issue

Answer (score 1):

```
if(preg_match ("/[^0-9]/", $total_bids)){ 
    return json_encode(array('error' => 'Please enter a valid Number.'));
}
```